# ElasticSearch Overload CPU

Tags: geonetwork, debian, elasticsearch

I have a server with Debian in which GeoServer and GeoNetwork are installed. I install ElasticSearch for GeoNetwork and every time I start this service, after a while the CPU overloads and the server freezes and stops responding. I have looked for the problem in the logs but so far I have not been able to find the error; maybe someone can tell me.

Comment: There's not much we can do without a lot more information: The system specs, the full logs,...

Comment: I have ruled out that Elasticsearch is causing this problem, since I stopped the elasticsearch process but the server froze again and the process that I now saw that was not responding was tomcat9; and the message I got when executing service tomcat9 status in the console was the following: Failed with result 'oom-kill' tomcat9. My server specifications are: Virtualized on vmware, OS Debian, 8 GB RAM, 250 GB disk. Freezing usually happens once a week

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to clarify. This doesn't seem like a GIS-centric issue.